# Setting up dimension to track post types

Tags: google-analytics

I have several post types on my site and in UA I liked being able to see how many page views I got each day for all of the different post types and I could also see which posts of a particular post type were getting the most views. e.g. Which Reviews got the most views within date range.

I am trying to get this working with GA4 and I keep hitting walls, It seems incredibly confusing. I read up on this yesterday and took the following steps

Admin->Custom Definitions->Create custom dimensions

Under here, I have created a dimension with the event parameter of "post_type".

On my website, I have the following

```
gtag('event', 'page_view', {'post_type': 'Review'});
```

If i view the report page for the page_view event, I see there is an option to add comparison. I click this and then pick Page View under the custom dimension. This then creates a dropdown where I must select dimension values. The dropdown is empty. I dont understand why I need to pick a value in the first place, nor why the dropdown is empty. I have a few other dimensions that I tracked using UA that had 1000s of potential values. I cant possible tell GA4 about every possible value.